# Error to Request a Certificate From a Certificate Authority on Mac Keychain Access

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I'm trying request CSR to apple developer, but I have an error:

> The user name or phassphrase you entered is not correct.

I'm following the steps: Keychain Access > Certificate Assistant > Request a Certificate From a Certificate Authority...

I put the same email of ios developer account, common name, saved to disk and the error happens.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it!

On Keychain Access > Keychains > login was unlocked, I locked it and tried again and it worked.

I hope be useful

Comment: Didn't work. Still the same error. The specified item was not found in the key chain. Any ideas?